# In a function declaration, what's the difference between void fun(const string& a) and void fun(string a)?

Tags: c++

I know (correct me if I'm wrong) that `const string& a` is an lvalue reference and `string a` is a simple string variable, but I'd like to know if, in this context, there's a difference between the two, because in some tutorials I saw people using `const [type]& var` instead of the simple `[type] var`.

What's the purpose of using one of the two declaration?

Thanks

Comment: You said it. One's a reference. References and values have different semantics.

Comment: Ok, but what's the purpose of doing this?